# How should one interpret 0.5 threshold for a binary feature in a decision tree used for trading?

Tags: decision-tree, trading, quantitative-finance

**How should I intepret a 0.5 threshold for a decision tree´s binary feature?**

I am trying to create a trading strategy by "reverse engineering" a trained decision tree model into a rule based trading strategy. The model uses several hundreds of features based on price action and economic calendar events. The resulting decision tree seems to put some importance on the feature whether on that trading day happened an economic event with medium importance. The feature "has_medium_events" is a binary feature, hence 1 = medium impact economic events happened, 0 = no medium impact economic events happened. However the trained decision tree shows a <= 0.5 threshold for this particular feature. How should I intepret it? does this mean that on 50% of days where there were medium impact economic events the model returned a true positive signal? If so, why is this feauture important?

I set the threshold of "has_medium_events" to <= 0.5, but this seems meaningless, as then the strategy would trade only on the days where no medium economic events happened. Why would the model not set the threshold to = 0 ?

I am using python and sklearn for this model.